# warning: connect.session() memoryStore is notdesigned for production environment as it will leakmemory and will not scale past a single process

Tags: node.js, session, memory-leaks, session-cookies

Code snippet

```
app.use(
expressSession({
secret: config.secret,
resave:true,
saveUninitialized: false,
cookie: {
 httpOnly: true,
}
}

)
)
```

warning: connect.session() memoryStore is notdesigned for production environment as it will leakmemory and will not scale past a single process. Memomry leak issue

The above is the code snippet, I'm using express-session, please advice how to fix the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.